# How can I download a package and its dependencies for OpenSUSE on windows?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, zypper, yast

Somehow I have a computer using OpenSUSE without internet connection. I want to download some packages and their dependencies on windows and install them in OpenSUSE. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from a DVD or ISO image.

For the DVD usually there is a repository for the DVD. Check this by either YAST or Zypper looking at your Repos.

```
Zypper lr
```

To make a ISO file to use as a Repo saving time and having to have the DVD handy.

1. mkdir ~/sources
2. use dd for making a iso image you can mount [Tutorial on making a iso](http://file:///home/marc/Downloads/Command_Line_dd_and_mkisofs.pdf)

   ```
   dd if=/dev/sdx1 of=~/sources/OpenSUSE_DVD_13_X.iso
   ```
3. Now add the ISO as a software repository

   zypper ar -c -t yast2 “iso:/?iso=/home/USERNAME/sources/OpenSUSE_DVD_13_X.iso” “openSuSE 13.X″
4. Verify the repo with `zypper lr`
5. List the repos and delete the DVD repo by using the number seen in `zypper lr`

Remove the repo for the DVD that is listed in the repo suing its number

```
sudo zypper rr X
```

6. You can now use `sudo zypper ref` and than `zypper search X`